# PHP or Javascript date and time code from both server and local time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Does anybody have a simple code for showing week nr, date and time taken from the webserver?

And then another code that gets the time from the local computer?

I'm looking for a JS or PHP code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server side you can use (`PHP`)

```
$currentWeekNumber = (int)date('w'); // ISO-8601 week number of the year
$date = date('H:i:s d-m-Y'); // for example (you can use different format)
```

JS implementation is not so trivial. There is no built-in function, but here is an example of what is done.

```
function getWeek (getdate) { 
        var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, n, s, w; 

        $y = getdate.getFullYear(); 
        $m = getdate.getMonth() + 1; 
        $d = getdate.getDate(); 

        if ($m <= 2) { 
            a = $y - 1; 
            b = (a / 4 | 0) - (a / 100 | 0) + (a / 400 | 0); 
            c = ((a - 1) / 4 | 0) - ((a - 1) / 100 | 0) + ((a - 1) / 400 | 0); 
            s = b - c; 
            e = 0; 
            f = $d - 1 + (31 * ($m - 1)); 
        } else { 
            a = $y; 
            b = (a / 4 | 0) - (a / 100 | 0) + (a / 400 | 0); 
            c = ((a - 1) / 4 | 0) - ((a - 1) / 100 | 0) + ((a - 1) / 400 | 0); 
            s = b - c; 
            e = s + 1; 
            f = $d + ((153 * ($m - 3) + 2) / 5) + 58 + s; 
        } 

        g = (a + b) % 7; 
        d = (f + g - e) % 7; 
        n = (f + 3 - d) | 0; 

        if (n < 0) { 
            w = 53 - ((g - s) / 5 | 0); 
        } else if (n > 364 + s) { 
            w = 1; 
        } else { 
            w = (n / 7 | 0) + 1; 
        } 

        $y = $m = $d = null; 

        return w; 
    } 

weeknumber = getWeek(new Date());
```

---

**UPD:** Today, [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/) is capable of many things regarding dates in JS.

Comment: Found on http://tech-hacks.net/common/72/get-the-week-number-with-javascript-update/